# Using floats in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am making a sort of dashboard with widgets. I want there to be two sizes of widgets (large and small). I had thought if I floated the larges ones to the left and the small ones to the right that they would fill up the screen but it is not working how I expected.

**What I want to achieve:**

[image: desired]

**What I am getting:**

[image: actual]

**My Code**

CSS

```
.l, .r{
    border:1px solid gray;
}

.l{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

.r{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style='width:320px;'>
    <div class='l'>left1<br />second line</div>
    <div class='r'>right1</div>
    <div class='l'>left2</div>
    <div class='r'>right2</div>
    <div class='r'>right3</div>
    <div class='r'>right4</div>
    <div class='r'>right5</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vader88/s0gk83t4/

I do realize that if I put right2 before left2 in the dom that it would fix the current layout but I want it to be more dynamic than that and fill the screen properly no matter the height of any of the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the secondary widget elements to wrap around the entire set of primary widget elements, I suggest that you put all of the left widgets inside one div.  Then float all the secondary-widgets to the right.  That will make the trailing secondary widgets line up as in your example.  There will still be some issues to work out with the stacking of the secondary widgets (see jsfiddle), but the basic concept should work.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="main-widget-area">
        <div class="main-widget">left1<br />second line</div>
        <div class="main-widget">left2</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="secondary-widget">right1</div>    
    <div class="secondary-widget">right2</div>
    <div class="secondary-widget">right3</div>
    <div class="secondary-widget">right4</div>
    <div class="secondary-widget">right5</div>
</div>
```

The css then looks like this:

```
.container {
    width: 320px;
}

.main-widget-area {
    width: 215px;
    float: left;
}
.main-widget{
    border:1px solid gray;
    width:200px;
}

.secondary-widget{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s0gk83t4/8/

Comment: Unless I am missing something this leaves space at the top of the right side. http://jsfiddle.net/f029c504/

Comment: Mike, my demo displays exactly as you requested.

Comment: It doesn't work on my part : [ScreenShot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QdkMv.png) : **4** and **5** are reversed from what OP asked.

Comment: This is much better than what I had and I will probably end up using it. But I am wondering if there is a way to fix the fact that right3 is pushing right4 and right5 down. http://jsfiddle.net/s0gk83t4/7/

Comment: @Mike The only way you can fix this is have **right3** on the left, then **right4** then **right5** on the same row to the right of **right3**. Else, you can't fix this.

Comment: @Sifu Thanks for the info and thanks for pointing out that this answer reversed right4 and right5. However in my situation I don't mind that.

Comment: @Sifu is right.  You can change the float to right on the secondary widgets, but that creates some other problems.  For example:  http://jsfiddle.net/s0gk83t4/8/

Answer (score 0):

you can simply achieve it by putting the divs right 1,2,3,4 in a new div and float the div to left

Comment: The thing is I like how they can collapse down into a single column if the width of the page gets too small. That why I was trying to do it this way.